# gcc/clang lay out fields of a derived struct in the back-padding of base struct

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, padding

I'm confused with how gcc and clang lay out structs when both padding and inheritance are involved. Here's a sample program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A
{
    void* m_a;
};

struct B: A
{
    void* m_b1;
    char m_b2;
};

struct B2
{
    void* m_a;
    void* m_b1;
    char m_b2;
};

struct C: B
{
    short m_c;
};

struct C2: B2
{
    short m_c;
};

int main ()
{
    C c;
    memset (&c, 0, sizeof (C));
    memset ((B*) &c, -1, sizeof (B));

    printf (
        "c.m_c = %d; sizeof (A) = %d sizeof (B) = %d sizeof (C) = %d\n", 
        c.m_c, sizeof (A), sizeof (B), sizeof (C)
        );

    C2 c2;
    memset (&c2, 0, sizeof (C2));
    memset ((B2*) &c2, -1, sizeof (B2));

    printf (
        "c2.m_c = %d; sizeof (A) = %d sizeof (B2) = %d sizeof (C2) = %d\n", 
        c2.m_c, sizeof (A), sizeof (B2), sizeof (C2)
        );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
c.m_c = -1; sizeof (A) = 8 sizeof (B) = 24 sizeof (C) = 24
c2.m_c = 0; sizeof (A) = 8 sizeof (B2) = 24 sizeof (C2) = 32
```

Structs C1 and C2 are laid out differently. In C1 m_c is allocated in the back-padding of struct B1 and is therefore overwritten by the 2nd memset (); with C2 it doesn't happen.

Compilers used:

```
$ clang --version
Ubuntu clang version 3.3-16ubuntu1 (branches/release_33) (based on LLVM 3.3)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

$ c++ --version
c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

The same happens with -m32 option (sizes in the output will be different, obviously).

Both x86 and x86_64 versions of Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C++ compiler don't have this issue (i.e. they lay out structs С1 and C2 identically)

If it's not a bug and is by design, then my questions are:

1. what are the precise rules for allocating or not allocating fields of a derived struct 
   in the back-padding (e.g. why it doesn't happen with C2?)
2. is there any way to override this behaviour with switches/attributes (i.e. lay out just like MSVC does)?

Thanks in advance.

Vladimir

Comment: http://mentorembedded.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout For POD types, the whole type is left alone (supposedly for compatibility with C). For types that are clearly not C (say if you add a destructor to B2) it reuses the padding.

Comment: That document doesn't really cover this issue. It mostly delegates to the C ABI and doesn't explain why it has the algorithm it has.

Comment: @Puppy that document specifies the exact rules for layout, saying that it doesn't cover the issue is... strange.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: It doesn't mention, for example, the changed rules in the Standard about this. Or legacy ABIs. Or layout for PODs.

Comment: "We ignore tail padding for PODs because an early version of the standard did not allow us to use it for anything else and because it sometimes permits faster copying of the type."

Answer (score 6):

For everyone downvoting this question and OP's self-answer with self-righteous indignation over how terribly UB his hand-written `memcpy` was... consider that the implementors of both libc++ and libstdc++ fall into the exact same pit. For the foreseeable future it is actually *really important* to understand when tail-padding is reused and when it's not. Good on OP for bringing up this issue.

The Itanium ABI rules for struct layout are [here](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout). The relevant wording is

> If D is a base class, update sizeof(C) to max (sizeof(C), offset(D)+nvsize(D)).

Here "the dsize, nvsize, and nvalign of [POD types] are defined to be their ordinary size and alignment," but the nvsize of a non-POD type is defined to be "the *non-virtual size* of an object, which is the size of O without virtual bases [and also without tail padding]." So if D is POD, we never nestle anything into its tail padding; whereas if D is *not* POD, we are allowed to nestle the next member (or base) into its tail padding.

Therefore, any non-POD type (even a trivially copyable one!) must consider the possibility that it has important data stuffed into its tail padding. This generally violates implementors' assumptions about what's permissible to do with trivially copyable types (namely, that you can trivially copy them).

[Wandbox test case:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sMSfmwPX6Ftj4kkz)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>

struct A {
    int m_a;
};

struct B : A {
    int m_b1;
    char m_b2;
};

struct C : B {
    short m_c;
};

int main() {
    C c1 { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    B& b1 = c1;
    B b2 { 5, 6, 7 };

    printf("before operator=: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4
    b1 = b2;
    printf("after operator=: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4

    printf("before std::copy: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4
    std::copy(&b2, &b2 + 1, &b1);
    printf("after std::copy: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 64, or 0, or anything but 4
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour, as C and C2 are not PODs and memcpying over random bits of their data is not allowed.

However, in the slightly longer run, this is a complex issue. The existing C ABI on the platform (Unix) permitted this behaviour (this is for C++98, which permitted it). Then the Committee changed the rules incompatibly in C++03 and C++11. Clang, at least, has a switch to change to the newer rules. The C ABI on Unix, of course, did not change to accomodate the new C++11 rules for putting things in padding, so the compilers can't exactly just update, as that would break all ABI.

I believe that GCC is storing up ABI-breaking changes for 5.0 and this may be one of them.

Windows always banned this practice in their C ABI and therefore do not have a problem, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Can you name the clang option please? Also, the ABI-breaking changes in gcc-5 will be essentially in the library.

Comment: No, I can't. I only saw a couple bits of the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the compiler is allowed to use the padding of a previous object if that object is already "not just data" and manipulating it say with `memcpy` is not supported.

The `B` structure is not just data, because it's a derived object and therefore the slack space of it can be used because if you're `memcpy`-ing a `B` instance around you're already violating the contract.

`B2` instead is just a structure and backward compatibility requires that its size (including the slack space) is just memory your code is allowed to play with using `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everybody for your help.

The bottom line, C++ compilers are allowed to re-use tail-padding of non-POD structs when laying out fields of derived structs. 
Both GCC and clang make use of this permission, MSVC doesn't.
GCC seems to have -Wabi warning flag which should help catching cases of potential ABI incompatibilities, but it produced no warnings with the above sample.

It looks like the only way to prevent this from happening is injecting explicit tail-padding fields.

Comment: What, so you can continue to produce UB by memcpying it around? Just don't do undefined things.

Comment: The question was about laying out struct fields gcc/clang vs msvc, memset was just a mean of demonstrating what I mean. In any case, thanks, I got the information I needed.

Comment: `-Wabi` only applies between versions of GCC, see `-fabi-version`

Comment: `-Wabi` is not relevant here, since the rules that GCC follows come from the Itanium C++ ABI and have not changed between GCC versions (Clang also follows the Itanium C++ ABI, but MSVC doesn't)