# Standard-layout and tail padding

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++, standard-layout

David Hollman recently tweeted the following example (which I've slightly reduced):

```
struct FooBeforeBase {
    double d;
    bool b[4];
};

struct FooBefore : FooBeforeBase {
    float value;
};

static_assert(sizeof(FooBefore) > 16);

//----------------------------------------------------

struct FooAfterBase {
protected:
    double d;
public:  
    bool b[4];
};

struct FooAfter : FooAfterBase {
    float value;
};

static_assert(sizeof(FooAfter) == 16);
```

You can examine the layout [in clang on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/RivQ7z) and see that the reason the size changed is that in `FooBefore`, the member `value` is placed at offset 16 (maintaining a full alignment of 8 from `FooBeforeBase`) whereas in `FooAfter`, the member `value` is placed at offset 12 (effectively using `FooAfterBase`'s tail-padding).

It is clear to me that `FooBeforeBase` is standard-layout, but `FooAfterBase` is not (because its non-static data members do not all have the same access control, [[class.prop]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#prop-3.3)). But what is it about `FooBeforeBase`'s being standard-layout that requires this respect of padding bytes?

Both gcc and clang reuse `FooAfterBase`'s padding, ending up with `sizeof(FooAfter) == 16`. But MSVC does not, ending up with 24. Is there a required layout per the standard and, if not, why do gcc and clang do what they do?

---

There is some confusion, so just to clear up:

- `FooBeforeBase` is standard-layout
- `FooBefore` is *not* (both it and a base class have non-static data members, similar to `E` in [this example](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#prop-4))
- `FooAfterBase` is *not* (it has non-static data members of differing access)
- `FooAfter` is *not* (for both of the above reasons)

Comment: Who says that this behavior is "required" by anything in the standard? It could simply be a manifestation of how the compiler goes about implementing things.

Comment: @NicolBolas It may very well _not_ be required. MSVC does not do this (its `FooAfter` is also 24 bytes), but gcc and clang do - and it seems like that's a conscious choice on their parts.

Comment: "*it seems like that's a conscious choice on their parts.*" What makes you say that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334730/775806

Comment: It is *never* required that there is no padding between class members. It *may* be required that there *is* padding. So the correct question is not which part of the standard *requires* gcc to reuse the end-padding, but what *allows* it to do so in the second case. Another question is whether something disallows such reuse in the first case.

Comment: I think the right way to phrase this question is just the more general: Why do gcc and clang do what they do here?

Comment: @Barry: If that's the question you want answered, then it's a duplicate of the Q&A n.m linked to. They do it because the Itanium ABI says to do it.

Comment: You're also changing the access control of members, which can lead to changes of layout. Once you mark some members as private or protected, the compiler is free to potentially use processor features to ensure that access at runtime. (Not sure that any do, though.)

Comment: @NicolBolas I feel like the right answer to this question was split between multiple answers and comments on both of these questions, so I'm community-wiki-ing the answer here and marking the other as a duplicate of this one (... in two days).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer to this question doesn't come from the standard but rather from the Itanium ABI (which is why gcc and clang have one behavior but msvc does something else). That ABI defines [a layout](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout), the relevant parts of which for the purposes of this question are:

> For purposes internal to the specification, we also specify:
>
> - *dsize*(O): the *data size* of an object, which is the size of O without tail padding.

and

> We ignore tail padding for PODs because an early version of the standard did not allow us to use it for anything else and because it sometimes permits faster copying of the type.

Where the placement of members other than virtual base classes is defined as:

> Start at offset dsize(C), incremented if necessary for alignment to nvalign(D) for base classes or to align(D) for data members. Place D at this offset unless [... not relevant ...].

The term POD has disappeared from the C++ standard, but it means standard-layout and trivially copyable. In this question, `FooBeforeBase` is a POD. The Itanium ABI ignores tail padding - hence `dsize(FooBeforeBase)` is 16.

But `FooAfterBase` is not a POD (it is trivially copyable, but it is *not* standard-layout). As a result, tail padding is not ignored, so `dsize(FooAfterBase)` is just 12, and the `float` can go right there.

This has interesting consequences, as pointed out by Quuxplusone in a [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334730/2069064), implementors also typically assume that tail padding isn't reused, which wreaks havoc on this example:

> ```
> #include <algorithm>
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> struct A {
>     int m_a;
> };
>
> struct B : A {
>     int m_b1;
>     char m_b2;
> };
>
> struct C : B {
>     short m_c;
> };
>
> int main() {
>     C c1 { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
>     B& b1 = c1;
>     B b2 { 5, 6, 7 };
>
>     printf("before operator=: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4
>     b1 = b2;
>     printf("after operator=: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4
>
>     printf("before std::copy: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 4
>     std::copy(&b2, &b2 + 1, &b1);
>     printf("after std::copy: %d\n", int(c1.m_c));  // 64, or 0, or anything but 4
> }
> ```

Here, `=` does the right thing (it does not override `B`'s tail padding), but `copy()` has a library optimization that reduces to `memmove()` - which does not care about tail padding because it assumes it does not exist.

Comment: I think this answer is correct except for one thing: the working definition of POD _in the ABI_ is not the C++11 definition of "trivial + standard-layout", but rather what POD was back in C++03, which is basically an aggregate + some other restrictions on members (see 8.5.1 and 9p4). An aggregate has only public members. A standard-layout type may have non-public members, as long as all have the _same_ access level. So the upshot is that a class with only private numbers may be trivial copyable and standard-layout, hence POD in the C++11 sense, but _not_ POD in the C++03 sense and ...

Comment: ... so it _is_ eligible for re-use of padding as shown in this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
FooBefore derived;
FooBeforeBase src, &dst=derived;
....
memcpy(&dst, &src, sizeof(dst));
```

If the additional data member was placed in the hole, `memcpy` would have overwritten it.

As is correctly pointed out in comments, the standard doesn't require that this `memcpy` invocation should work. However the Itanium ABI is seemingly designed with this case in mind. Perhaps the ABI rules are specified this way in order to make mixed-language programming a bit more robust, or to preserve some kind of backwards compatibility.

Relevant ABI rules can be found [here](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout).

A related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334730/775806)  (this question might be a duplicate of that one).

Comment: TriviallyCopyable *does not work* if you [try to copy into a base class subobject](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#2).

Comment: The next question: why does the Itanium ABI designed this way? :)

Comment: @geza I don't know but my guess is up there in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a concrete case which demonstrates why the second case cannot reuse the padding:

```
union bob {
  FooBeforeBase a;
  FooBefore b;
};

bob.b.value = 3.14;
memset( &bob.a, 0, sizeof(bob.a) );
```

this cannot clear `bob.b.value`.

```
union bob2 {
  FooAfterBase a;
  FooAfter b;
};

bob2.b.value = 3.14;
memset( &bob2.a, 0, sizeof(bob2.a) );
```

this is undefined behavior.

Comment: "*this cannot clear bob.b.value.*" Since `FooBefore` is not standard layout, the common-initial-sequence rule doesn't apply. So you can't access `bob.a` after you've set `bob.b`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Why would `FooBefore`  not be standard layout?

Comment: @Holt: both `FooBeforeBase` and `FooBefore` has non-static members, therefore `FooBefore` has no standard layout.

Comment: @Holt A standard layout type has data members *either* in a base class *or* not in a base class, but not both. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType

Comment: @Holt: It's the "has no element of the set" part. That's what it says once you untangle all of the spec-language.

Comment: CIS doesn't matter anyway. It allows *reading* through a different member, not *writing*.

Comment: @t.c that is a surprise to me.  You certain?

Comment: Yes. See [class.mem]/25 in the current WP.

Answer (score -1):

`FooBefore` is not std-layout either; two classes are declaring none-static data members(`FooBefore` and `FooBeforeBase`). Thus the compiler is allowed to arbitrarily place some data members. Hence the differences on different tool-chains arise.
In a std-layout hierarchy, atmost one class(either the most derived class or at most one intermediate class) shall declare none-static data members.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a similar case as n.m.'s answer.

First, let's have a function, which clears a `FooBeforeBase`:

```
void clearBase(FooBeforeBase *f) {
    memset(f, 0, sizeof(*f));
}
```

This is fine, as `clearBase` gets a pointer to `FooBeforeBase`, it thinks that as `FooBeforeBase` has standard-layout, so memsetting it is safe.

Now, if you do this:

```
FooBefore b;
b.value = 42;
clearBase(&b);
```

You don't expect, that `clearBase` will clear `b.value`, as `b.value` is not part of `FooBeforeBase`. But, if `FooBefore::value` was put into tail-padding of `FooBeforeBase`, it would been cleared as well.

> Is there a required layout per the standard and, if not, why do gcc and clang do what they do?

No, tail-padding is not required. It is an optimization, which gcc and clang do.

Comment: But the standard doesn't allow `clearBase` to work on a base class subobject. Well, if we're going to be technical, `memset` isn't allowed on TriviallyCopyable types period, but even if that were a `memcpy` from a zero-initialized `FooBeforeBase` `static` instance, it still wouldn't be allowed on base class subobjects.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I nowhere stated that. As a user of `clearBase`, you may not know, what is inside. So, this behavior of the compiler guarantees that you don't shoot yourself in the foot. Please be a little bit more practical here, even if the question has the language-lawyer tag. We already talking about something, which is not covered by the standard (i.e., tail-padding optimization).

Comment: "*I nowhere stated that*". You very much did, right after you said: "*Now, if you do this:*". That's code which calls `clearBase` on a base class subobject, which is UB.

Comment: "But the standard doesn't allow clearBase to work" Rather, it doesn't *guarantee* that it will work.

Comment: @NicolBolas: okay then. This behavior is there too guarantee, that even if it is UB, it doesn't do any harm. UB doesn't automatically mean that something bad must happen.