# What causes difference of size of structs between inheritance and member?

Tags: c++, sizeof

I cannot understand the reason for difference in size of C and C2 in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    int* x;
};

struct B {
    A a;
    int y;
};

struct C : B {
   int z;
};

struct B2 : A {
   int y;
};

struct C2 : B2 {
   int z;
};
    
int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(A) << std::endl; // 8
    std::cout << sizeof(B) << std::endl; // 16
    std::cout << sizeof(C) << std::endl; // 24
    std::cout << sizeof(B2) << std::endl; // 16
    std::cout << sizeof(C2) << std::endl; // 16
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/GEWj2LQxloC34lNS

What I (probably) understand is that,

- C has the following memory layout

```
|0      |4      |8      |12     |16      |20     |
|A::x-----------|B::y---|padding|C::z----|padding|
```

- C2 has the following memory layout.

```
|0      |4      |8      |12      |
|A::x-----------|B::y---|C::z----|
```

In C, it seems that the padding of structure B remains, but in C2, it seems that the padding of structure B2 is packed. What is the cause of this difference? (Is it defined in the C++ standard? What kind of rule is it?)

Comment: Where which amout of padding is added is implementation-defined.

Comment: "What is the cause of this difference?" what do you mean exactly? The different size of `C` and `C2` ? Are you asking why `sizeof(C)=24` while `sizeof(C2) == 16` ?

Comment: @Hammer User.... there is no multiple inheritance in this question, that was the wrong duplicate.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 What I want to know is why the padding of B remains in C, but the padding of B2 does not remain in C2.

Comment: [this question and accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53837373/standard-layout-and-tail-padding) goes into some more detail (might be a considered a duplicate)

Comment: @Kevin yes that's the right duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ allows subobjects introduced in a derived class to overlap (padding in) base subobjects as long as those objects are not standard-layout. It does not allow any overlap between member subobjects, or overlap of a standard-layout base subobject.

Look at the size and layout of `struct B` to understand why `struct C` has internal padding.

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Why can't `C::z` overlap the padding in the base object `B`, but `C2::z` *can* overlap the padding in the base object `B2`? Or am I not fully understanding what "It does not allow any overlap between member subobjects" means?

Comment: @Kevin: You're right, I answered for `struct C { B base; int z; };`  Now expanded.

Comment: I think I understand now. `struct B` is standard-layout, but `struct B2` is not - one of the requirements for standard layout according to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType) is "Has all non-static data members and bit-fields declared in the same class (either all in the derived or all in some base)"

Comment: Yes, that's the essential difference.  Standard-layout subobjects have to be compatible with external code... if for example you pass a `struct C` to a function accepting `B*` with output parameter semantics and that function used `memcpy` to write to it, it'll trash the internal padding, which would ruin your day if some other object overlapped the internal padding.  C++ makes that safe when `B` is standard-layout.